# Javascript; local machine (no server); access iFrame content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm developing an HTML/JavaScript application that is intended for off-line user (remote areas, no internet, etc., etc)

I want to be able to "dynamically" list contents of a directory. Ideally what I want to do is to grab the contents of an iFrame like this:

```
<iframe id="content_iframe" height="0" width="0" src="./content/"></iframe>
```

Parse it and display it nicely.

I **strongly** suspect that this is impossible because the browser doesn't understand that both the parent HTML file and the SRC of the iFrame are on the same machine. i.e. that this isn't actually a cross domain issue.

The really frustrating part is that if I have:

```
$("#content_iframe").load(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

The console outputs all the text from the iFrame - if I could access that, then I could do my parsing and go along my merry way.

So, really, two questions:

1) How can I access the text (or HTML, whatever) inside an iFrame

2) Failing that, how can I - in JavaScript - get the text that console.log outputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Browsers consider the `file:///` protocol in Same Origin, so it sees local folder and doesn't accept it. You need a server, even if it's a local server.

Comment: Client Side JavaScript does not allow anyone to look into directories. You could use it in conjunction with Sever Code though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but you might be able to assign the "this" value to a variable and then manipulate as needed.

```
$("#content_iframe").load(function() {
var iframe_html = this.toString();
console.log(iframe_html)
});
```

Comment: No, all that gets dumped to the console is "[object HTMLIFrameElement]"